# undefined method `to_sym' for {:limit=>30, :string=>"Hint: ", :null=>false}:Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Why is it showing this error when i try to run `rake db:migrate`:

```
undefined method `to_sym' for {:limit=>30, :string=>"Hint: ", :null=>false}:Hash
```

Code:

```
def up
     create_table :users do |t|
            t.string "email", :limit => 50, :string => "Forgot password!", :null => false
            t.column "password", :limit => 30, :string => "Hint: ", :null => false
            :default 

            t.timestamps
        end
      end
```

Answer (score 2):

this line may need to change..

```
t.column "password", :limit => 30, :string => "Hint: ", :null => false
```

by

```
t.string "password", :limit => 30, :string => "Hint: ", :null => false
```